# Change color of the icons in a tabpanel in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, tabpanel

I know there is a general way to set the "theme" of the tabpanel [**through sass and compass**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159107/change-color-of-sencha-touch-ext-tabpanel) but what I would like to do is be able to set at will the color of each icon and be able to set a different color for each of them.

I have no idea of how to do that through sass...

Comment: Have you tried changing the color of the original icon ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the color of the original icon ?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of the icon in `touch-charts-full.css`

Comment: Can I use the original color of the icons ?

Comment: Nice, I'll have a look at that tonight !